# Receive Email with attachment from current Site source code

Tags: php, jquery, attachment, email-attachments

The idea is that the user can arrange div blocks (drag and drop) on the screen. When the user thinks the positions are good they can email me the positions with their name and email through a form.

```
<form action="#">       
<input name="name" id="name">        
<input name="email" id="email">       
<input name="htmlcontent" id="htmlcontent">        
<p><button type="submit">Send to DKdL</button></p>
</form>
```

The form will be filled by hand. Except for the field where the complete source code will be pasted in ( via jquery – will also be filtered here ). That's how I will later know what position every div block had. This will be send via jquery post.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {

var html = $('html').html();
var htmlSending = '<html>' + html + '</html>';
var noScript = htmlSending.replace(/script/g, "h6");

//alert(noScript);
$('input#htmlcontent').val(noScript);

$.post('http://www.address/save.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
    //callback to use for thank you message
    console.log(data);
});

e.preventDefault();
});
```

In the php i want the third field (with the copied and filtered html source code) to be saved as an .html file with the name and date behind it (example: peter_01-09-2012.html) and included in the email as attachment that will be send to me.

```
<?php

$name = name;
$email = email;
$htmlcontent = htmlcontent;
//file_put_contents('file.html', '$htmlcontent'); 

$to = '"My Email <my.email@mail.com>';
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 

$message =
<p>Name: $name</p>
<p>E-Mail: $email</p>
here should be a url to the HTML Content: $htmlcontent
or a real email attachment
;   
?>
```

Is this possible to achive? Unfortunately my knowledge doesn't reach in php. I just know that it is possible to write to files. But how can I tell php to include it in the email as an attachment? If there is a better alternative to my problem I like to hear it as well of course.

Comment: Just a question back: Why do you want to post the source-code when you only need to know the poistions of the divs?

Comment: When I become an Email and open the html file from the attachment and see 1:1 what the user saw instead of some numbers that I somehow have to convert to see how they positioned the divs.

Because the divs are spread around the complete document. An Image wouldn't reach because there is scrolling included.

Answer (score 0):

As PHP's `mail()` is actually a simple "proxy" to send raw e-mail content, you have two options:

1. Use some more functional package for PHP that allows you to construct mail message with attachments (such as PEAR Mail_Mime).
2. Learn how multipart mail content is build. As it is quite simple in this scenario (and involves only terms like `Content-type`, `Content-disposition`), therefor I would recommend it here.

The easiest is to learn by example, so please take some simple mail message (with attachment) in your e-mail client and view source of this message. You can even use this source as a template for the data you send to PHP's `mail()` function.

Comment: Hi Kuba,
thanks for your reply. I never thought of looking at the source code from an Email. I checked it and found the Content-type and Content-dispostion. I'm going to try out if I can solve this on my own now :)

`--Apple-Mail-F95B52F6-D7A8-4B9A-9223-969CF1587128
Content-Disposition: ATTACHMENT;
 filename="document.pdf"
Content-Type: APPLICATION/PDF;
 name="document.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: BASE64`